# Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I validate the presence of one field or another but not both and at least one ?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Your code will work if you add conditionals to the numericality validations like so:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :date
  validates_presence_of :name

  validates_numericality_of :charge, allow_nil: true
  validates_numericality_of :payment, allow_nil: true

  validate :charge_xor_payment

  private

  def charge_xor_payment
    return if charge.blank? ^ payment.blank?

    errors.add(:base, 'Specify a charge or a payment, not both')
  end
end
```

Comment: The functionality work great. But, I couldn't get the errors shown on the form page. Unless I do something like ´= @invoice.errors[:base][0]` on the my _form.slim. Any suggestions?

Comment: not working in this case :```validate :zipcode_xor_every_where```

Answer (score 55):

I think this is more idiomatic in Rails:

e.g: For validating that one of `user_name` or `email` is present:

```
validates :user_name, presence: true, unless: ->(user) { user.email.present? }
validates :email, presence: true, unless: ->(user) { user.user_name.present? }
```

Comment: This does not handle the "not both" criteria

Comment: Another downside, with this approach, if both fields are left blank the user is shown two slightly misleading errors: "Email can't be blank" and "User name can't be blank". Better to show a single error (as per the accepted answer) explaining at least one of them must be provided.

Comment: its not working in Active admin

Answer (score 16):

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :date
    validates_presence_of :name

    validates_numericality_of :charge, allow_nil: true
    validates_numericality_of :payment, allow_nil: true


    validate :charge_xor_payment

  private

    def charge_xor_payment
      if [charge, payment].compact.count != 1
        errors.add(:base, "Specify a charge or a payment, not both")
      end
    end

end
```

You can even do this with 3 or more values:

```
if [month_day, week_day, hour].compact.count != 1
```

Answer (score 10):

Example for rails 3.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :date
  validates_presence_of :name

  validates_numericality_of :charge, :unless => proc{|obj| obj.charge.blank?}
  validates_numericality_of :payment, :unless => proc{|obj| obj.payment.blank?}


  validate :charge_xor_payment

  private

    def charge_xor_payment
      if !(charge.blank? ^ payment.blank?)
        errors[:base] << "Specify a charge or a payment, not both"
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Validation using a [Proc or Symbol with :if and :unless](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) will get called right before validation happens.

So presence one of both fields may be like this:

```rb
validates :charge,
  presence: true,
  if: ->(user){user.charge.present? || user.payment.present?}
validates :payment,
  presence: true,
  if: ->(user){user.payment.present? || user.charge.present?}
```

The (example snippet) code has `:if` or `:unless` as latest item, however as declared in [doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) it will get called right before validation happens - so another checking will works after, if condition match.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that if both fields are left blank the user is shown two slightly misleading errors: "Charge can't be blank" and "Payment can't be blank". Better to show a single error (as per the accepted answer) explaining at least one of them must be provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
 validate :father_or_mother
```

#Father last name or Mother last name is compulsory

```
 def father_or_mother
        if father_last_name == "Last Name" or father_last_name.blank?
           errors.add(:father_last_name, "cant blank")
           errors.add(:mother_last_name, "cant blank")
        end
 end
```

Try above simple example.

Answer (score 1):

I put my answer to this question below. In this example `:description` and `:keywords` are fields which one of this not be blank:

```
  validate :some_was_present

  belongs_to :seo_customable, polymorphic: true

  def some_was_present
    desc = description.blank?
    errors.add(desc ? :description : :keywords, t('errors.messages.blank')) if desc && keywords.blank?
  end
```