# Adding OR operator for validates in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model, where I need to make sure that, either one of the two fields has to be filled up and other one needs to be left empty.

e.g. I have a reward_file and reward_link field in a model. I need to make sure that

1. Either reward_file and reward_link must have a value
2. Both must not have values (Mutually exclusive)

I am using rails 3

Can anyone provide a solution of this?

Examples can be:

reward_file has value, reward_link is empty #valid

reward_file is empty, reward_link has value #valid

reward_file is empty, reward_link is empty #invalid

reward_file has value, reward_link has value #invalid

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an XOR validation method. One possible solution is shown [in this question: Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor). Hope this is applicable!