# Rails 3 Validation, only one field should be present out of two, and other should be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Model package.rb

```
  validates_presence_of :duration, :unless => :expiration_date?
  validates_presence_of :expiration_date, :unless => :duration?
```

I want only one of these needs to be entered. Other field must be set to nil. only one of them needs to have value.
but still i can create a package with both of these fields. May be other I am missing something or do i need to use other method? is this not the correct way of doing this?

Comment: See [Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom validation.

```
validate :expiration

def expiration
  unless duration or expiration_date
    errors.add_to_base "Need a way to determine expiration"
  end
end
```

Comment: no help, I can still create a package with both, I need only one, and after change, or entered one of them other needs to be nil.

Comment: You can't use `or` here: `or` and `and` are control-flow modifiers, `&&` and `||` are logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
require 'active_model'

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :aa, :bb

  validate :only_one_present

  def initialize(options = {})
    self.aa = options[:aa]
    self.bb = options[:bb]
  end

  private

  def only_one_present
    if both_present || no_attr_present
      errors.add(:base, 'Invalid!')
    end
  end

  def both_present
    !aa.nil? && !aa.empty? && !bb.nil? && !bb.empty?
  end

  def no_attr_present
    (aa.nil? || aa.empty?) && (bb.nil? || bb.empty?)
  end
end

puts Person.new(aa: 'asad', bb: 'sdsd').valid? # => false
puts Person.new(aa: nil, bb: 'sdsd').valid? # => true
puts Person.new(aa: 'asad', bb: nil).valid? # => true
puts Person.new(aa: nil, bb: nil).valid? # => false
```

Of course you have to write proper specs first and you can extract validator class for this.

**EDIT:**

You can change `nil?` and `empty?` combination for `present?` or `blank?` if using ActiveSupport.