# validates_presence_of at least one of these associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `WithdrawalAccount` record contains either a `SepaAccount`, `InternationalAccount`, `PayPalAccount` or `OtherAccount`. Should be at least one of these. Can not be more than one.

```
class WithdrawalAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sepa_account
  has_one :international_account
  has_one :third_account
  has_one :fourth_account
end
```

**Updated Question:** 
How can I `validate_presence_of` either one of them while allowing only one of them present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
class WithdrawalAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sepa_account
  has_one :international_account

  validates :sepa_account,          presence: true, if: ->(instance) { instance.international_account.blank? }
  validates :international_account, presence: true, if: ->(instance) { instance.sepa_account.blank? }
end
```

To validate either one you should prefer the following method:

```
class WithdrawalAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :accounts_consistency

  private

  def accounts_consistency
    # XOR operator more information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor
    unless sepa_account.blank? ^ international_account.blank?
      errors.add(:base, "options consistency error")
    end
  end
end
```

**With more than 2 attributes to validate:**

Since the XOR will **not work** with more than 2 attributes (`a ^ b ^ c`) we could check the attributes using a loop:

```
def accounts_consistency
  attributes = [sepa_account, international_account, third_account, fourth_account]
  result = attributes.select do |attr|
    !attr.nil?
  end

  unless result.count == 1
    errors.add(:base, "options consistency error")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you validate that only one can be present? either `sepa_account` or `international_account` but only one?

Comment: This seems to have a flaw when having 4 attributes to do XOR. For instance: `nil ^ true ^ true ^ true` returns `true`. If someone push 3  types of account at the same time, looks like this XOR conditions will take them all as good.

Comment: That's an excellent question. I'll digg into it to see what I can come up with

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
validate :account_validation

private

def account_validation
  if !(sepa_account.blank? ^ international_account.blank?)
    errors.add_to_base("Specify an Account")
  end
end
```

There is answer here([Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor))

Comment: thanks, please see updated answer. how would you manage 4 values in this scenarios while keeping it easier to read?