# Rails validate that attribute_a exists OR attribute_b exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In rails 4.0.0, I need to validate that either attribute_a exists on my model or attribute_b exists on my model. One of them must exist, and both of them can not exist at the same time.

How can I write that validation?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor

Look there for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validates_numericality_of :charge, allow_nil: true
validates_numericality_of :payment, allow_nil: true


validate :charge_xor_payment

private

def charge_xor_payment
  if !(charge.blank? ^ payment.blank?)
    errors.add(:base, "Specify a charge or a payment, not both")
  end
end
```

Another way:

a or b last name is compulsory

```
validate :a_or_b 
def a_or_b
    if a == "Last Name" or a.blank?
       errors.add(:a, "cant blank")
       errors.add(:b, "cant blank")
    end
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor)

Comment: Did you really just copy the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor without any credit to the source? Please point to where you got your answer if it's not original.