# Rails 4 validates presence conditional "style"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to DRY this up a bit, but can't figure out what the syntax might be. I have two fields that I want to conditionally validate presence of: link and text. Each should require presence if the other is not #present?, but require absence if the other is #present?

This is as short as I can get it and it feels icky having to have each field broken into two parts.

```
validates :link,
        presence: true,
        unless: "text.present?",
validates_absence_of :link, if: "text.present?"

validates :text,
        presence: true,
        unless: "link.present?"
validates_absence_of :text, if: "link.present?"
```

Can anyone else help a n00b make it cleaner?

Thanks in advance.

**Found Solution**

I ended up going with the below solution with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor).

```
validate :either_or

private

  def either_or
    if !(link.blank? ^ text.blank?)
      errors[:base] << "Specify a link or text, but not both."
    end
  end
```

Comment: the updated solution is good

Comment: Please add your solution as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question ;)**

I ended up going with the below solution with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor).

```
validate :either_or

private

  def either_or
    if !(link.blank? ^ text.blank?)
      errors[:base] << "Specify a link or text, but not both."
    end
  end
```

Comment: Approve your own question