# Validate presence of one field or another or both(OR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor) but I'm wondering how to do an 'OR' instead of an 'XOR'. Does anyone know how to do this? I am trying to do this using Rails 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. all you have to change is the ^ to &&

```
private
def time_or_money
  if time.blank? && money.blank?
    errors[:base] << "Specify Time, Money or Both."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

There is short option for Rails 4 (not sure about  Rails 3) :

```
validates :email, presence: { if: -> { username.blank? } }
validates :username, presence: { if: -> { email.blank? } }
```

Comment: The OP's answer is better than this one from a UX point of view. With this approach, if both fields are left blank the user is shown two slightly misleading errors: "email can't be blank" and "username can't be blank". Better to show a single error explaining at least one of them can't be blank.