# Conditional Rails Form Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a rails model that has two field attributes: `:commission_fixed` & `:commission_percentage`. The user should only be able to choose between one of the two options either: `:commission_fixed` or `:commission_percentage` not both on form submit. Is this possible using Rails validation? If so what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Keep a dropdown or select option , what's stopping you . You can use jquery to stop multiple selection on radio buttons .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder How can we make select box for two attributes, is it possible AFAIK We can send options to a single attribute as select box right

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know I can achieve it this way, my questions was more out of curiosity and if it can be achieved purely through using Rails validation.

Comment: If you just want to validate a particular field , then you can do so by mentioning presence: true in the attribute model

Comment: Thanks @CaffeineCoder I comfortable with Rails validation just wanting to know if my above question is possible.

Comment: It's possible but not purely with rails , you will be needing jquery or javascript to achieve what you are aiming for as that's what used for client side validations .

Comment: I guess in your case if you want any one attribute to be selected by the user, then you'll lose the ability to validate using `presence: true`.

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Surely it must be possible to write a custom if else method ?

Comment: I think this might answer my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is within the way you've structured your column names / model attributes.

Ideally you should change your attribute names on your model to `:commission_method` and `:commission_rate`. This allows for greater flexibility. Then in your view you can achieve what you're looking for with a radio button. You can store your `:commission_rate` as a decimal in the db.

```
<%= f.radio_button :commission_method, "Fixed" %>
<%= f.radio_button :commission_method, "Percentage" %>
<%= f.number_field :commission_rate %>
```

In your view files if you need to switch between showing a fixed amount and a percentage you can just do:

```
<% case @sales_associate.commission_method %>
<% when 'Fixed' %>
  <span>Fixed: <%= number_to_currency(@sales_associate.commission_rate) %></span>
<% when 'Percentage' %>
  <span>Percentage: <%= "% #{@sales_associate.commission_rate}" %></span>
<% end %>
```

However, you "could" write a custom validation method that throws an error if both attributes were assigned.

In whatever model:

```
class SalesAssociate
   validate :only_one_selected_commission

   def only_one_selected_commission
     errors[:base] << "Please select only one form of commission" if self.commission_fixed.present? && self.commission_percentage.present?
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful, well informed and articulate answer. I see what you mean with the column names / model attributes I will rewrite this to reflect your answer. Cheers