# Rails validation to allow nil for either one of the field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two fields `first_name` and `last_name`

How do I write a validation that permits `first_name` or `last_name` to be `nil`, but not both?

I have tried:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, allow_blank: true
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an XOR validation method. One possible solution is [shown in this question: Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor). Hope this is applicable!