# Rails validations presence of either one of two fields (XOR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I validate that either one of these values is present, but not both?

```
  validates_presence_of :client_id, message: 'Please enter a value'
  validates_presence_of :agency_id, message: 'Please enter a value'
```

I looked on the rails guides and I think I need to use conditional validations, but I'm still a little stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate presence of one field or another (XOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this

```
validates :client_id, presence: true, unless: :agency_id
validates :agency_id, presence: true, unless: :client_id
```

If you want to include the error message, you can do

```
validates :client_id, presence: { message: "Must have a value" }, unless: :agency_id
```

You can read more about [validation messages](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)

Comment: how can I keep the message there with this syntax?

Comment: I think you can just add the message part from you had

Comment: I get a MessageValidator error if I put the message back on

Answer (score 8):

If you use the unless syntax, you will get 2 errors: one when client_id and one when agency_id if both are Nil.

You would need a custom method if you want only one error.  [Guides: ActiveRecord Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

```
validate :client_or_agency

def client_or_agency
  errors.add(:client_id, "Either Client or Agency needs a value") unless client_id.present? || agency_id.present?
end
```